# firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, storage

I'm stuck on this problem and cannot fix that. I want to connect to my firebase storage via React but I get this warn:

> getFirebase(...).storage is not a function

I have tried everything and I'm still getting this piece.

My function:

```
export const createNails = (nail) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    [...]
   };
```

Config in fbConfig.js that I import to index.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

var firebaseConfig = {
  app data
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {
  createFirestoreInstance,
  reduxFirestore,
  getFirestore,
} from 'redux-firestore';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from 'config/fbConfig';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig)
  )
);

const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
};

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <App />
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I need to import 'firebase/storage' in top of the config file like auth and firestore.